# What is the optimal number of solr cores for one drive.

Tags: solr, lucene

`Manning: Solr In Action`  says:

> If you have multiple cores on the same server, it's a good idea to use separate physical disks for each index. - Chapter 5: Indexing

My understanding is that in Solrcloud, one core is synonymous to one shard. Does it mean that number of shards on a host should ideally be equal to number of disks - with each shard on its own disk?

If above understanding is correct and I decide to keep one shard per drive:- Is there any recommended upper limit on size of shard?

Does this above discussion matter if disk is SSD?

Answer (score 0):

With SSDs index time perf gets a huge boost versus spinning disk. So, you can follow that recommendation you mention, but it would not have as much effect with SSDs.

Also, as always 'optimal' depends on what you want to optimize for. Indexing perf or query perf? If it was query perf, you would want to take the number of cpu cores into account too. In the end, you should just take a good sample of your data and test different setups so you can see trends, then decide.

Comment: Any suggestion about when not using SSD? Any upper limit on shard size in that case?

Disks are huge these days, but can we make one shard that big just because we want one shard per drive?